# Edit cron in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I was wondering if anyone know a way how to display and edit crons from a certain user in PHP? I've tried googling and I couldn't come up with anything.

Alternatively, is there a way to set a certain cron with an ID, so that it's easier to find for editing purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some commands to:

1. export current crontab: `crontab -l > /some/file`
2. do your own cooking with editing this file via php
3. tell cron to use your edited file : `crontab /some/file`

using `exec()` to run those commands should be fine.

Ith seems there are also some libraries out there that would do this for you, like [Jobby](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby)...